# Memory mapped register, how it actually works

Tags: memory

When the OS defines a memory map, e.g. APIC is mapped to a certain address, when a program issues assembly STA address value, how is it insured that the DDR controller rejects this address and how does the device, i.e APIC know the address correlates to its register so it can accept the data on the data bus? Is this set up with OCW/ICWs?, in the larger picture, do all devices have some onboard memory map table the OS needs to configure?

Comment: Memory mapping of registers occurs at the hardware level.  The memory address decoder determines if the address references RAM or a device register.  This memory address decoder is typically hardwired.

Comment: Where does the memory address decoder reside, is it part of the mmu after the virtual physical address translation ,  I assume the OS can write to it and configure it?

Comment: A memory address decoder has to be separate from any MMU or processor cache, since both of those are optional (i.e. they can be disabled).  The decoder would be part of the system bus logic.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_decoder   *"I assume the OS can write to it and configure it?"* -- When something is *hardwired*, it cannot be configured by software.  For PCI an extension of the address decoding involves Base Address Registers, which AFAIK could be the only configurable aspect of memory address decoding.